# OpenCV and Windows Store App using C# on a x64 platform

Tags: opencv

We are trying to integrate an OpenCV C++ Windows Runtime Component with a C# Windows Store App. We are currently working on Windows 8 (x64) platform and using Visual Studio 2012 with OpenCV 2.4.5. The actual aim is to detect faces in a C# Windows Store App working on x64 platform. We successfully set up OpenCV 2.4.5 with Visual Studio 2012 (x64 platform) and copied all the dll's of openCV to the "system32" folder so that we are able to build and run the openCV projects on the above mentioned platform.

Here are the problems faced by us:

1. We are successful in building the C++ Windows Runtime Component that contains the code for the face detection. But as soon as we integrate that with the Store App and try to make the object of the WinRT's class. It throws an exception.
2. But the whole project works fine if we comment the lines where we are trying to work on images and cascades.

Solely we are able to detect faces in  Win32 Console application using the above code. But not able to do the this task.

I am giving the link to the project we are working on.
"https://www.dropbox.com/l/OkEZNMrazzFmV6UOj59KMb"

About the project:
1. "FaceDetectWinRT" is the C++ Windows Runtime Component project which contains "Class1.cpp" and "Class1.h" which contains the code for the face detection.
2. "FaceDetectStoreApp" is the C# Windows Store App project that has the reference to the above project and is declared as the "Start up" project.
3. There is a button in the " FaceDetectStoreApp " under "MainPage.xaml.cs" class which when clicked calls the " FaceDetectWinRT " project's function "face" which when working is expected to return the coordinate of the face that is detected.

Comment: long post, but the essential info missing ;(  --   *what exception* do you get, when you call the opencv code ?

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing with very similar results. I had success when deploying the WinRT app on an ARM device. You need to:

1. Include the OpenCV dlls in the C# project marked as "Content"
2. Don't forget the highgui dll. The objdetect dll depends on it.
3. Make sure you reference all the OpenCV .lib files, one per OpenCV dll
4. Switch the configuration to ARM in the Configuration Manager
5. Deploy to a device running ARM (i.e. the Surface) usually done through Remote Debugger

I have not yet had success running the app on a x86 device (i.e. the Surface Pro). I believe the problem is that the objdetect dll depends on the highgui dll. The ARM build of the highgui dll only depends on a few standard libraries. The x86 build depends on several additional libraries that aren't available for WinRT. I think you might be able to get it to work by building OpenCV for x86 without highgui. You can do this by setting the BUILD_opencv_highgui CMake variable to OFF.